# Sort Array of Objects Based on number of Keys it contains

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

This is a sample code but it does not seem to sort the array. All I want is the array of object sorted in such a manner that the object with maximum keys comes first.

```
CSVData.sort(function(item1,item2){
                            return Object.keys(item2).length - Object.keys(item1);
                        });
```

Comment: You forgot `.length` after `Object.keys(item1)`?

Comment: Oh snap.. Thanks for pointing out. I was scratching my head trying to figure out what I did wrong.

Comment: here u are finding the difference between thte item2 number of items with the item1. :P

Comment: How do I close the question now? Don't want the downvotes :P

Answer (score 4):

You were close

```
CSVData.sort(function(item1,item2){
   return Object.keys(item1).length - Object.keys(item2).length;//notice the length property here
});
```

Also notice that `item1` is before `item2`, assuming that you want to sort in ascending order. For descending order, it will be

```
   return Object.keys(item2).length - Object.keys(item1).length;
```

Comment: Thanks Gurvinder. I did forget the length property actually.

Comment: And I've to sort it in the descending order only.